# Assign ID to each row in Microsoft sql server view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

Lets say I have a table like this:

```
create table MyTable (
 Myname varchar (10) primary key not null
```

) 
and a few row of data like:

```
insert into MyTable values ('john');
insert into MyTable values ('Brad');
insert into MyTable values ('James');
insert into MyTable values ('Anna');
insert into MyTable values ('Eric');
insert into MyTable values ('Hossein');
```

I want to create a view that assign an ID to each row, 
I have used the select statement below :

```
   select rank() OVER (ORDER BY Myname) as ID, MyTable.Myname 
   from MyTable 
   order by ID
```

The results is quite acceptable, But the problem come out when I try to create view

```
create view myview as 
 select rank() OVER (ORDER BY Myname) as ID, MyTable.Myname 
   from MyTable 
   order by ID
```

My questions are:

1- how can I create the view from the select statement mentioned above?

2- Is there any alternative way that I can use?

Comment: What is the problem with your query, other than the fact that you are using `order by` in a view without a `top`?

Comment: Thank you so much for the awesome answer.
No. by removing order by ID it is still work.

Comment: @HoseinDjadidi Gordon's answer below addresses your specific issue better than my answer. If you accept his answer I can delete mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order by` is not allowed in a view unless you use `top`.  As per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx):

> The SELECT clauses in a view definition cannot include the following:
>
> - An ORDER BY clause, unless there is also a TOP clause in the select list of the SELECT statement

So, your statement is fine without the `order by`:

```
create view myview as 
   select rank() OVER (ORDER BY Myname) as ID, MyTable.Myname 
   from MyTable ;
```

Even if you include the `order by` with a `top`, the results are not guaranteed in a particular order.  You can only guarantee that by using `order by` the outer query.

Comment: The actual Data set is quit big and it is sorted based on date (almost 15000 row of data), is there any probability that the ID assigned to the each row of view, become out of order ?
thank you .

Comment: (1) 15,000 rows is not big.  (2) The rank is defined by the database and recalculated each time you run, so it cannot be "out of order".  The resulting data set may not be returned in order, but the rank will be properly assigned.